# Create a view based on filesize column and apply filter in a document library

Tags: 2013, 2010, sharepoint-server

in a web application there is a document library and daily 1000 to 2000 documents are uploaded by users,

so here i want to calculate the  average size of documents uploaded to this web application, so here i want to create a view based filesize column and apply filter on this column.

ex: filesize >500 KB

Comment: What condition you would want to have in your filter? Like you would want to show documents whose file size is greater than 500KB?

Comment: i did not fount filesize column in filter condition while i creating a view..i taken the 500 kb is for example. i will check in some range values like 500 - 1000 kb and 1000 - 2000

Comment: There is a column with internal name "FileSizeDisplay" try to create a view using that column programatically, or export any listview webpart and update the query

Answer (score 2):

You can create a view with `File Size` placed in the query using `CSOM PowerShell`. I have used the query mentioned by @Yayati. You can replace with yours.

this function need not compulsorily run on the SharePoint server. You can also run it from your remote machine provided you have `Client Object Model` namespaces on your remote machine.

```
function Create-ListView()
{
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$url,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][System.Net.NetworkCredential]$credentials,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$listName,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$viewName
    )

    begin{
        try
        {
            #get Client Object
            $context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($url)
            $context.Credentials = $credentials

            #Retrieve List
            $list = $context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($listName)
            $context.Load($list)
            $context.ExecuteQuery()


        }
        catch
        {
            Write-Host "Error while getting context. Error -->> "  + $_.Exception.Message -ForegroundColor Red
        }
    }
    process{
        try
        {
            $viewQuery = '<Where><Lt><FieldRef Name='File_x0020_Size' /><Value Type='Number'>10000</Value></Lt></Where>' 
            $viewFields = New-Object System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection  
            $viewFields.Add("Title")
            $viewFields.Add("File_x0020_Size")
            $ViewInfo = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ViewCreationInformation
            $ViewInfo.Query = $viewQuery
            $ViewInfo.RowLimit = 50
            $ViewInfo.ViewFields = $viewFields 
            $ViewInfo.Title = $viewName
            $ViewInfo.SetAsDefaultView = $false



            $view = $list.Views.Add($ViewInfo)
            $context.Load($list.Views)
            $context.ExecuteQuery()
            Write-Host "View added successfully" -ForegroundColor Green

        }
        catch
        {
            Write-Host ("Error while creating view for a List. Error -->> " + $_.Exception.Message) -ForegroundColor Red
        }
    }
    end{
        $context.Dispose()
    }


}
```

Usage:

```
$credentials = Get-Credential
Create-ListView 'http://yoursite' $credentials 'Your Library Name' 'Name of your view'
```

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. The `FileSize` column is by default is not visible in filter section of View. So you can create a custom view using SharePoint Designer by using CAML Query.
Here are steps to create custom view:

1. Go to Document Library settings -> Create View -> Custom View in SharePoint Designer
2. Open the custom view in SharePoint Designer.
3. Search for `<View>` tag and replace `<Query/>` tag with your CAML Query. e.g. here is the query to show file having filesize < 10kb

   ```
   <Query><Where><Lt><FieldRef Name='File_x0020_Size' /><Value Type='Number'>10000</Value></Lt></Query></Where>
   ```

   (**Note :** I have taken 1kb = 1000 bytes)
4. Save your view and if required make it default.

Comment: i will try this and let you back

Answer (score 1):

Provided you have a **View with the FileSize column displayed** all the information is available in de `ctx` object.

You can process this with CSR or in a CEWP

*Proof of concept code in F12 Dev Tools:*

```
function countFileSize(min,max){//in bytes
    var total=0,
        count=0;
    ctx.ListData.Row.forEach(function(row){
        var size=parseInt(row.File_x0020_Size);
        console.log('item ID',size,'item ID:',row.ID,row.FileLeafRef);
        if(size>min && size<max){
            count++;
            total+=size;
        } else {
            console.error('outside boundaries:',size,row.FileLeafRef);

        }
    });
    console.info('With boundaries:',min,max,' there are',count,'files','totalling',total,'bytes');
    return(total/count);
};
console.clear();
var average=countFileSize(0,100000);//bytes
console.info( 'average:',average,'bytes' );
```

iCSR