# Create View that Groups items within 2 Groups

Tags: view

Is it possible to create a View that groups items on File Size?  Specifically, I want to show all items in a library in 2 groups: files less than 10MB and another group for files greater than 10MB.  Then sort on File Size within the 2 groups.  Thanks for any help provided.

Answer (score -2):

Use 2 ListViews with Filters on one page to do the first 'Grouping'

Comment: Filter on a List View does not show File Size column.

Comment: Are you on 2013 or Online?

Comment: SharePoint 2010

Comment: So that means no CSR. Is the Filesize available in a Workflow so you can write it to another text column?

Comment: Here are some script answers: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/152771/create-a-view-based-on-filesize-column-and-apply-filter-in-a-document-library/159917#159917